# Is it possible to install IIS 7.5 or 7 on windows8

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

Is it possible to install IIS 7.5 or 7 on windows 8?

Comment: I did search but didn't get any proper answer

Comment: Is there any reason you would want to? You cannot install IIS 7.5 or 7, however there is an IIS6 compatibility extension you can install when you go through the setup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer - no.

Slightly longer answer - Since IIS 5.0 the version of IIS is tied to the version of the OS and it is now treated as an OS component.  Windows 8 will run IIS 8 and there will be no means of installing a different version.